# Can't make a request twice

Tags: node.js, express

So,I've set up this route which gets JSON data from an internal API and displays it.The first time I visit the route I get the correct JSON data but when I refresh the page I get an error and the page just stucks loading.Any ideas?
Note: I use request-promise

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
var options = {
//Here I initiate the API call.I actually have a url here.
uri: '',
json: true   
};

request(options)
    .then(function(data) {
        res.json(data);
        res.end();
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: *"when I refresh the page I get an error"* - which is...?

Comment: HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT.I removed caching and now it works but I don't know how is caching related.I cache the responses from the API.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error in console and the page stuck loading because the api you are calling gave an error response but you are not sending anything in the catch callback. try this.

```
  app.get('/',function(req,res){
    var options = {
        //Here I initiate the API call.I actually have a url here.
        uri: '',
        json: true   
    };

    request(options)
        .then(function(data) {
            res.json(data);
            res.end();
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send(err); // set proper error code and send response here
        });
  });
```

Comment: Just a quick one I may be wrong here but in the `then` block` shouldn't we be doing a res.send(data) as apposed res.end? I know oyu didn't put that in just thinking without the res.send() method being fired the response will never succeed :p

Comment: res.send() calls res.end() for you.

Comment: @Jackthomson Do read the documentation on [`res.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json). It takes the role of `res.send()` for JSON content.

Comment: agree @E_net4 no need to call res.end after calling res.json